# Bind Websocket Message in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, sockjs

I'm stuck with my mini project, I have a feeling it's something trivial...

I am trying to bind websocket messages to angular datamodel. I don't seem to be able to do that...

Below my controller and a little bit of html to display the data.

```
    controllers.WebsocketController = mainModule.controller('WebsocketController', function($scope){
    $scope.test = 'test string';
    var socket = new SockJS('/dashboard');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/dashboardEntries', function(message){
            $scope.dashboardEntries = message.body;
        });
    });
})
```

That's what I'm using to display the data:

```
<div id="dateDiv" class="container" ng-controller="WebsocketController">
    <p id="response"> {{dashboardEntries}} </p>
    <p id="response1"> {{test}} </p>
</div>
```

I cannot seem to understand why the test data object is displayed and the dashboard entries are not... I debugged my code and I am getting these messages - also I was able to populate that paragraph using jQuery, but data binding does not seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.$apply();
```

did the trick...

Comment: where did you apply